# System Center  icon doesn't show when pinned to launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, pinning

On Natty Narwhal, I dragged System Center to the launcher. Instead of an icon, I get a blank square on the launcher. Clicking on it does launch the system center, though. This issue does not happen with other apps I pinned to the launcher.

Comment: This sounds like a bug - if you could report this as a bug that'd be great. For more on that, take a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Try switching to (or from) theme 'Radiance'.  This may simply be a simple icon issue, which an update (or different choice of theme) will resolve.

Comment: Do you mean the system settings?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this happened after upgrade? So try to remove those icons from launcher, and drag them again into the launcher e.g. from /usr/share/applications. That worked for me. Please also check this question [Icons missing from launcher, system settings, folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78285/icons-missing-from-launcher-system-settings-folders) and its answer.